# How to make a key shape using css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to make a html div containing a shaple like this: [image]

Using a bit of costume css in a html table, I can make a table with a rounded avatar on one column alongside a rectangular box in another column but can not make the circle to overlap the rectangle like the above picture.

Appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a :pseudo-element to do this.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #B0B4FF;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/125/125);
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

You could change the `background-image` through JavaScript.

The JavaScript code will loop through the stylesheet rules, find the rule for `#info:after` and change its `backgroundImage` to the one specified.

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "#info:after" || r.selectorText == "#info::after") {
      r.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://dummyimage.com/125/125/0f8d94/0011ff&text=newImage)'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#info {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #B0B4FF;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
#info:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/125/125);
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

---

Since you can't change the `background-image` through CSS, you'll need an `img` tag and since :pseudo-elements don't apply on `img` tags, you'll have to use another `div` for the rectangle.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 325px;
}
.info {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #B0B4FF;
  margin: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/125/125);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Info Text</div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/125/125" />
</div>
```

---

Satisfying the title, **A Real Key Shape**:

[image]

```css
#container {
  width: 325px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg viewBox="-2 -2 206 103">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="circ">
        <rect id="rect" x="1" y="1" width="98" height="98" rx="100" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0,50 a50,50 0 0,1 96.9846,-17.101 m-96.9846,17.101 a50,50 0 0,0 96.9846,17.101 l10,10 q5,3 6,-3 v-12.5 h12.5 l7,7 l10,-12 l10,12 h7 l10,-12 l7,7 h8 l16,-15.5 q5,0 -16,-10 h-71.5 v-12.5 q0,-6 -6,-3 l-10,10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="saddlebrown"
    stroke-width="2" fill="tan" />
    <path d="M100,51 h97 l-1.5,2 h-85z" stroke="saddlebrown" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
    <text x="110" y="48" font-size="6">Info Text</text>
    <image clip-path="url(#circ)" width="98" height="98" x="1" y="1" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 50%;" xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/a77243/000000&text=Real Key Shape" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice but since avatars are rendered dynamically (from django template) I can not use 'background: url' in css.

Comment: @hbsd - I can show you how to change that url using JavaScript or you want to change the url in HTML?

Comment: well my preferred answer is using pure html/css but if you think it is not possible please elaborate the js-helped solution.